# How objects are compared in java?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

So for a long time i thought that objects are compared using `equals()` which uses `hashcode()` , which means if 2 objects have same hash code it returns true.

The equals() method from source code:

```
@see java.lang.System #identityHashCode
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (this == obj);
    }
```

So i created this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog rover = new Dog("Rover");
        Dog german = new Dog("Rover2");

        System.out.println("German: " + german + "\tRover: " + rover);
        System.out.println(german.equals(rover));


    }
```

Also i overridden the hashCode() to:

```
    @Override
    public final boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        //The main point of 0 is to check how equals actually work
        return 0;
    }
```

Now the print statement is printing false even both objects are @Dog0.
Wondering why
Console:

```
German: Animal.Dog@0    Rover: Animal.Dog@0
false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `equals` as an "alias" for the `this == obj` comparison **which is wrong** and that's why it doesn't work.

Objects have the `equals` method because `this == obj` only returns true if it is actually the very same object (same reference in memory).

What you need to do is manually compare the properties in the `equals` method and only return true if they match.

Comment: So when dealing with objects it looks on memory address rather than hashcode to return a true?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It looks if you are "pointing" to the same object and has nothing to do with hashcode.

Answer (score 1):

The reason they are not "equal" has nothing to do with hash codes.

The reason they are not equal is this condition:

```
this == obj
```

which returns `true` only if `obj` is *the same* object as `this`.
You have 2 objects, so that can't be true.

Also, as you can see from the source code, calling `equals()` does not call `hashCode()`. AFAIK, there's *no* implementation (in the JDK anyway) where `equals()` calls `hashCode()`.

Comment: Maybe the confusion arose because how `Object`'s `toString()` is implemented. It prints: `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())` and `Òbject`'s default `hashCode()` implementation converts object's **internal address** into an integer. This internal address is also what the `==` operator is using, hence the confusion.

Comment: Maybe its worth to add this to your answer: equals() and hashCode() are tied together by contract: If o1.equals( o2) returns true then o1.hashCode() == o2.hashCode must be true as well. The opposite is not always true: Two objects can have the same hash code, but equals may nevertheless return false (i.e. with very big strings).